# Cyber Talent Basic Malware Reverse Engineering

Tags: ida, ghidra, radare2

I'm an absolutely beginner in the reverse engineering field. I have an exe program and I am to find:
[image: Answer to the question to be provided]

I have tried with Ghidra but i keep getting wrong submissions for the challenge.

Here is the exe file : https://talentchallenges.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Reverse/CybertalentDemo0.exe

I'll be very happy for your help. Thanks.

Comment: what values have you tried?

here is what I found:
0x004012c9 0x00401100 0x004020f8